# find all entire functions that are 1-1

Tags: complex-analysis

That is all the given information.

I should find all the entire functions that are one to one, I have no clue on how to do that.

And there is also another one, that goes like this:

Find all entire functions that are:

$$\forall z \in \mathbb C^* \;\;\;\;\; \lvert f(z)\rvert \le \lvert \frac{\sin z}{z} \rvert$$

$$\mathbb{C}^* \text{ is complex plane without } (0,0)$$

Comment: Please ask only one question per post, and [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, there are four cases to consider: constant functions, polynomials of degree $1$, polynomials of degree $>1$, and non-polynomials. The first two cases are obvious. For the third case the derivative is a non-constant polynomial and thus has zeroes, and holomorphic functions are not one-to-one near where their derivatives vanishes. For the last case, $f(\frac{1}{z})$ has an essential singularity and thus takes on almost every value in $\mathbb{C}$ repeatedly as you go to the origin (Picard's theorem). So only the degree $1$ polynomials are injective.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick :)

Comment: That is not what the Casorati Weierstrass theorem says: all it says is that if $f$ has an essential singularity at $p$ (which may be either in $\Bbb{C}$ or equal to $\infty$), then the range of $f$ when restricted to any neighborhood of $p$ is dense in $\Bbb{C}$. To use the Casorati Weierstrass theorem to prove that entire functions with essential singularities cannot be one to one, you have to use the open mapping theorem as an intermediate step.

Comment: Right I was thinking of Picard's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Observe that if a function $f$ is entire and one to one, then $f$ cannot have an essential singularity at $\infty$ by the great Picard's theorem. This means the Taylor series expension of $f$ at $0$ has only finitely many terms, and thus $f$ is a polynomial. Now note that a polynomial is one-to-one if and only if the degree is $1$.